# Can I use these images for a college publication?

Tags: copyright

I am a photo editor for a campus magazine. I am wondering about the use of publishing some of the images on 2008/0210728. It's about a solar backpack patent. Is this legal for a university to use? Are the images for public use or educational purposes?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is the link to the imigas i am asking about.http://www.google.com/patents/US20080210728

Comment: I would assume that "editorial" use of images from a patent application would fall under the fair-use doctrine; i.e. as long as your publication is talking about the patent and not trying to use them for other profit-making purposes.